# Disable alphabetical sorting in ag-grid using the basic model

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I use server side sorting with ag-grid. So far I used the enableServerSideSorting property set to true. But after version upgrade this property is not available.

I use the onSortChanged event to capture the sort state of the grid. And I want to handle this sorting on the server side. So ag-grid only display the data in the original order as it comes from the server. Now I sort the data outside the grid and then ag-grid sorting again alphabetically.

I created an example for this. There are two component property setSortParams where I set the sorting and data where I get the data already sorted.

How can I prevent the double sorting?

```
const ExternalGrid = ({ data, setSortParams }) => {
  const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      {
        headerName: "Quantity",
        field: "quantity",
        sortable: true
      }
    ],
    defaultColDef: {
      sortable: true
    }
  };

  const onSortChanged = params => {
    const sortModel = params.api.getSortModel();
    setSortParams([
      sortModel.length > 0,
      sortModel.length > 0 ? sortModel[0].sort === "desc" : false
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="ag-theme-balham"
      style={{
        height: "180px",
        width: "300px"
      }}
    >
      <AgGridReact
        gridOptions={gridOptions}
        modules={AllCommunityModules}
        onSortChanged={onSortChanged}
        rowData={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-server-side-sorting-chy7j

You can see in the example, that I display the data under the table. My goal is that it has the same order in the table whatever order I set clicking on the table header.

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/

Comment: @Nico I think filtering is not apply here. Ag-grid handles sorting and filtering separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you implement the following comparator in every column definition, the grid will not modify the row order when it sorts:

```
columnDefs: [
  {
    headerName: "Quantity",
    field: "quantity",
    sortable: true,
    comparator: (valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) => 0
  }
],
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-server-side-sorting-fmmgf

Comment: That is a viable solution, thanks. I updated your answer with the exact solution and the updated example.

Answer (score 1):

While working with server side row model, you should not assign the `rowData` directly (`rowData={data}`). Instead, create `ServerSideDatasource`. When you sort on any column, you will be able to get details as parameters for `getRows` method.

You could use it to provide sorting info to the server.

Reference: [Implementing the Server-side Datasource](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-infinite/#implementing-the-server-side-datasource)

Have a look at this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/z8KzsZ8sAcCe9tYWJedS?p=preview.

When you sort on a column, observe that you get the details by `params.request.sortModel` inside `dataSource.getRows` method.

```
[{
  colId: "athlete"
  sort: "asc"
}]
```

Comment: I do not mentioned that I use Redux with the basic model. This way the data is more decoupled from the grid. I'm aware of the server-side datasource, but I'm try to use it just as the last resort. I implemented notification, url update and infinite scrolling with redux and the basic model. My first priority to change as little from the current implementation as possible. Do you have any other idea?